# WASM Swagger Could not deserialize the response body

Tags: c#, swagger

I have a .net5 WASM project and separate API.

I have created a "Connected Service" in the WASM using the API Swagger Endpoint and the VS2019 "wizard". Everything coded up perfectly.

When calling the first endpoint, to retrieve data to be displayed in the WASM I am getting the error

> System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Sherpr.OpsCalendar.WASM.SherprAPIService.CalendarViewModel

When i look at the data coming from the API in Fiddler it all looks perfectly fine.

When I debug the code generated from the swagger definition it hits the following line:

```
var responseData_ = response_.Content == null ? null : await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I can see 111,032 bytes of data in response_.Content _data

But responseData returns a null which is then causing the deserialize problem i believe.

I can't work out whether the generated code is wrong or something else.

Can anyone shed any light please?

Here is the complete code generated by the connected service wizard...

```
if (status_ == "200") 
{
   var responseData_ = response_.Content == null ? null : await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); 
   var result_ = default(CalendarViewModel); 
   try
   {
          result_ = (CalendarViewModel)System.Convert.ChangeType(responseData_, typeof(CalendarViewModel));
          return result_; 
   } 
   catch (System.Exception exception_) 
   {
          throw new SwaggerException("Could not deserialize the response body.", (int)response_.StatusCode, responseData_, headers_, exception_);
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

After some further testing...

```
jsonContent = await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

this works:

```
CalendarViewModel calendarViewModel1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CalendarViewModel>(jsonContent);
```

this throws Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Sherpr.OpsCalendar.WASM.SherprAPIService.CalendarViewModel:

```
CalendarViewModel calendarViewModel2 = (CalendarViewModel)System.Convert.ChangeType(jsonContent, typeof(CalendarViewModel));
```

Comment: The problem is (most likely) because you're casting `responseData_` somewhere, you need to deserialize the content you `ReadAsStringAsync()` earlier

Comment: @MindSwipe i didn't write this code though. it was generated by the "Connected Service" VS2019 wizard... if i manually change it then it will get overwritten next time i update the "definition" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in version 13.2.0.0 of NSwag

https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2596

The temporary fix is to add

```
[Produces("application/json")]
```

to your API controllers